# Travel router connected to employer network.

Tags: networking

I bought an ethernet jack splitter and connected a tp link travel router in router mode to the network. I have it secured by velcro behind a file cabinet and remove it daily when I go home.

As far a security is concerned, what can they see on their end? I have all my phone and tablet connected to this new network using a vpn on each device. Work PC is on their network.

People check their bank accounts, medical records, etc. at work. I would like to keep these types of searches secure if that is even possible on a work network.

Comment: Are you already looking for a new job, or waiting until they sack you?

Answer (score 1):

It's one thing asking question that your local IT may be better able to answer, it's quite another asking how to circumvent their policies and procedures entirely.

To answer your question though: A properly configured network and a basically aware Network Admin would be able to see everything you're doing.

- A firewall will see and report the tunneled connections.
- System policy tools would see and report your initiating a network connection other than the ones approved for your computer.
- Network monitoring tools would see your little piece of junk attached to their network.

So what else is there? You are using their network to do your personal stuff. Is internet too hard to get at home? On your smart phone?

Come on. Don't be stupid. Put the toys away and do your job, then go home and check your bank accounts or whatever.

Comment: Also, if his travel router's wireless is enabled, business class Wi-Fi products will see the beacons of the rogue AP and report it even if he's set it to hide its SSID.

Comment: circumvent policies......... LOL

Comment: You do realise it's a sackable offence in most companies to bypass their security & add your own devices? If your device compromises their system, heads will roll a lot higher up than you.